# Problems with implementing inviting feature

Tags: python, django

I am working on the social network project and want to create feature that will give me opportunity to invite users to communities with invite url(UUID).Who can explain how to do that, i have tried to do that with context processors,but it doesn't work

```
models.py
class Room(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
students = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='room_students',blank=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,related_name='room_subjects',blank=True)
stream_time = models.TimeField()
max_students_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
room_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=TYPES)
invite_url = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

views.py
@login_required
def submit_invite(request,room):
invite_url = request.get.GET['key']
room = get_object_or_404(Room,slug=room)
user = request.user
if room.invite_url != invite_url:
    return HttpResponseNotFound
room.students.add(user)
return room.get_absolute_url()

@login_required
def join_room(request,room): 
room = get_object_or_404(Room,slug=room)
user = request.user
room.students.add(user)
return HttpResponse(room.students.count())

urls.py
    path('rooms/<room>/invite?key=<invite_url>/',submit_invite,name='sumbit_invite'),
```

Comment: you can generate an invite link for each user and save it in your user table or a table linked to your users or sth like that ...

Comment: but why to generate link for each user, if i am doing that for each group, i just want to know how to implement function that will automatically join to community if you willl go to this url and redirect to community detail page

Comment: yea I thought you want to know which user invited a person, yes similar scenario. for the rest of the things you want, I think it is based on your code and structure. `somebody opens the link > you find the url in your database > call your join_to_group API > redirect  user to the community`

Comment: yes, but i am not working with api, is it possible to do that without api or in other way?

Comment: I think since Django is usually function base or class base, you may have to write a function or a method to do something.  so I assume you should have a function/method for joining the community, wherever it is, you should get the user request and do something with that.  I think you should put some code to your question to show what did you do till now.

Comment: Your question is very vague and thus cannot be answered. What exactly is your problem? By calling the API he means you just register your new user for your group. We can only give vague answers because your question is unclear, the problem is with the questions not the answers...

Comment: added code above